# Why does node.js install two 'node_modules' folders?

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs, npm, package

Whenever I try to run `npm install` or `npm start` I get this error:

```
bash: line 0: cd: packages/react-scripts: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! aristophanes@1.0.0 start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the aristophanes@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-09T12_14_19_704Z-debug.log
```

I've no idea why I started getting it. Can anyone shed some light? I've tried uninstall and installing again but it doesn't help. Also, I don't know why but *node.js* installs 2 `node_modules` folders in my computer - one in my `C://Program Files/nodejs/` directory and another in `C://Users/Aristophanes/`. The two *package.json* files in each are different.

**Error log:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\Aristophanes/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~prestart: aristophanes@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: aristophanes@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\cmder\bin;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Users\Aristophanes\Go\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\PHP;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Geth;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\composer;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\local\bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin;C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\cmder
10 verbose lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Aristophanes
11 silly lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start' ]
12 silly lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle aristophanes@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: aristophanes@1.0.0 start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
15 verbose pkgid aristophanes@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Aristophanes
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 verbose node v10.13.0
20 verbose npm  v6.4.1
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error aristophanes@1.0.0 start: `cd packages/react-scripts && node bin/react-scripts.js start`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the aristophanes@1.0.0 start script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in C://Program Files/nodejs is the global packages that you are installing.

The one in the project are the dependencies for the project.

And this problem is probably ocurring because you are running npm install on a folder without a package.json.

Comment: I have a package.json in the directory I'm running npm install in though.

Comment: Basically the same error it shows in the console. I've added it to the end of the question, thanks.

Comment: delete node_modules on the folder and make npm install again

Comment: Done, but at the end of the installation I  get the exact same error. The log is too big to paste so here's a link to it, thanks https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9k4odys54q73wv/2018-11-09T12_43_22_991Z-debug.log?dl=0

Comment: I think maybe you have to use yarn instead of npm. check this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4308

Comment: Hmmm, I installed yarn and now If I use the command `npm yarn install` or `npm yarn start `I'm at least not getting those errors anymore. Have to say, its a bit confusing why this happened and now I have to use Yarn :/ Thanks for the help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think you have to use yarn after you install the react libraries, but I'm not sure. It seems facebook uses yarn so you have to execute their script with it maybe.

Comment: The react libraries have been installed, but if I use `npm start` I get the same old errors as before, whereas `npm yarn start` displays the information correctly. It's a mystery to me why this started happening, but at least I can do stuff for the time being now.

Comment: Nope, actually it's just displaying the usage information rather than going ahead and running. Ugh this problem is neverending.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having this challenge because you are not in your project folder navigate into your project folder then do your installation .just cd then the name of your app and press the enter key
// like this:

PS C:\Users\Alice\Desktop\project-folder> cd react-app

Answer (score 0):

I haven't sourced any explainer as to why the two `node_modules`.  Noticing that the one in `./Program Files/nodejs` are default pkgs while those in my `Users` dir are 3rd party added via `npm`.  Noticing also in the latter the presence of `package-lock.json` which will lock the version while the former contains only `package.json`.